# What is this fungus in my indoor snake plant's pot, and is it harmful?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, pest-control, plant-care, fungus

I've had a snake plant growing indoors for about a year. Twice now in the last month I've had to remove some fungus that sprouted over the surface.  The planter is located next to a patio door, which was open (we also have a screen door) for most of the spring, but is kept closed in the summer/winter.

Is this bad? Should I get rid of the plant, or perhaps re-pot it? What kind of fungus is this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fungus is digesting partly decomposed organic matter in the potting mix. They do not harm the plant. Also, the parts above the ground is only the reproductive body, you can remove them if you don't like the look, and the mycelia will still work on the medium.

Throwing away or repotting the plant is unnecessary, the fungus is beneficial if anything, because it breaks down the unusable material in the pot into something the plant can access.

I'm not certain what species that is. The picture is not very clear. This isn't very important, but if you want, post closeup picture of the fungus so we can try for a positive id.

Your [*Sansevieria trifasciata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria_trifasciata) cultivar is showing slight signs of [etiolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation). They tolerate dense shade, but dense shade looks a lot brighter indoors than out. Also, they (unusual) like to be root-bound. From the picture, it looks like you are doing a good job keeping the mix dry, but I'd provide just a little more light.

Comment: Technically speaking this is not fungus but mushrooms.

Comment: @kevinsky Technically, all mushrooms are fungi, but not all fungi are mushrooms.